# how to make autocomplete field in android studio

Tags: java, android

I created new simple application in android. I, have text box that is city field, I want auto complete for that field, If I use string array means how can I put all Indian cities. Its looking not good. Can anyone tell shortest way.

Comment: use `AutoCompleteTextView` with Array of cities.

Comment: you want to put a dropdown for that.?

Comment: use spinner if you dont wont to use textview

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm
The answer is in this tutorial .

Comment: so many cities is there.. how can i put 100 cities names inbuilt in  array

Comment: @appu comma-seperated, `String[] language ={"C","C++","Java",".NET","iPhone","Android","ASP.NET","PHP"};  `

Answer (score 0):

If you want to auto-complete itself with the help of gps, Here's the code.

```
GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

// check if GPS enabled
if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, 

 Locale.getDefault());
 List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
 String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
 String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
 String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
 TextView.setText(cityName);
 } 
 else 
 {
  gps.showSettingsAlert();
 }
```

**OR**

**If you want to use a auto-complete Text View**

Use this [guide](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example)